# Snowflake query: Count based on between dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake database that basically has scheduled payments and any fees endured by the loan: similar to this

| Date | Action | Amount | Loan_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Scheduled Payment | 100 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | NSF Fee | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | Payment | 110 | 1 |
| 2023-01-08 | Scheduled Payment | 100 | 1 |
| 2023-01-08 | NSF Fee | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-01-09 | NSF Fee | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-01-15 | Payment | 105 | 1 |
| 2023-01-22 | Scheduled Payment | 100 | 1 |
| 2023-01-22 | Payment | 100 | 1 |

I want to be able to count the NSF fees that occurred between scheduled payments. In the example I gave there are 3 scheduled payments, one have 1 NSF fee, one has 2 NSF fees, and the last has 0 NSF fees. How can I query the table to count the fees to know which payment they belong with? Here is what I am thinking now:

```
with payment_schedule as (select * from TABLE where action = 'Scheduled Payment'),
nsf_fees as (select * from TABLE where action = 'NSF Fee')

select pay.date, count(nsf.date) over (partition by pay.date) as nsf_count from payment_schedule pay join nsf_fees nsf on pay.loan_id = nsf.loan_id
```

I expect a table having each payment date, with the corresponding count of NSF fees associated with that date.

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have thought about using a window function, however being I am trying to account for number of  fees per payment period it makes me trip up.

Comment: Ok - so update your question with the SQL you have managed to write and explain where you are stuck. Hint - in a CTE use a window function to get the “end date” for each Scheduled Payment and then you’ll have the date range within which to count the fees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple to hand roll:

firstly you identify your event "schedule payment":

```
with data(Date, Action, Amount) as (
    select * from values
        ('2023-01-01'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        ('2023-01-02'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        ('2023-01-03'::date,    'Payment', 110),
        ('2023-01-08'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        ('2023-01-08'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        ('2023-01-09'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        ('2023-01-15'::date,    'Payment', 105),
        ('2023-01-22'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        ('2023-01-22'::date,    'Payment', 100)
)
select *
    ,iff(action = 'Scheduled Payment', Date, null) as event
from data
order by 1;
```

[image]

then you carry that values over the group:

```
select *
    ,iff(action = 'Scheduled Payment', Date, null) as event
    ,iff(action = 'Scheduled Payment', Date, lag(event) ignore nulls over (order by date)) as event_group
from data
order by 1;
```

[image]

Then you count across those groups, I have done a windowed count, as where/what you plan to do with this is not described, but this just shows, it can be done:

```
with data(Date, Action, Amount) as (
    select * from values
        ('2023-01-01'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        ('2023-01-02'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        ('2023-01-03'::date,    'Payment', 110),
        ('2023-01-08'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        ('2023-01-08'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        ('2023-01-09'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        ('2023-01-15'::date,    'Payment', 105),
        ('2023-01-22'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        ('2023-01-22'::date,    'Payment', 100)
), grouped as (
select *
    ,iff(action = 'Scheduled Payment', Date, null) as event
    ,iff(action = 'Scheduled Payment', Date, lag(event) ignore nulls over (order by date)) as event_group
from data
)
select * exclude (event, event_group)
    ,count_if(action = 'NSF Fee') over (partition by event_group) as payment_counts
from grouped
order by 1;
```

[image]

### Free lunch version:

Now the above find an event and group it logic can be replaced with [CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_true_event) which does this for you, is pretty much the exact way.

```
select *
    ,conditional_true_event(action = 'Scheduled Payment') over(order by date) as event_group
from data
```

[image]

### ID's:

```
with data(ID, Date, Action, Amount) as (
    select * from values
        (1,'2023-01-01'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        (1,'2023-01-02'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (1,'2023-01-03'::date,    'Payment', 110),
        (1,'2023-01-08'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        (1,'2023-01-08'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (1,'2023-01-09'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (1,'2023-01-15'::date,    'Payment', 105),
        (1,'2023-01-22'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        (1,'2023-01-22'::date,    'Payment', 100),
        (2,'2023-01-01'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        (2,'2023-01-02'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (2,'2023-01-02'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (2,'2023-01-03'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (2,'2023-01-03'::date,    'Payment', 110),
        (2,'2023-01-08'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        (2,'2023-01-08'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (2,'2023-01-09'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5), 
        (2,'2023-01-10'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (2,'2023-01-11'::date,    'NSF Fee', 5),
        (2,'2023-01-15'::date,    'Payment', 105),
        (2,'2023-01-22'::date,    'Scheduled Payment', 100),
        (2,'2023-01-22'::date,    'Payment', 100)
), grouped as (
    select *
        ,conditional_true_event(action = 'Scheduled Payment') over(partition by id order by date) as event_group
    from data
)
select * 
    ,count_if(action = 'NSF Fee') over (partition by id, event_group) as payment_counts
from grouped
order by 1,2;
```

[image]

Comment: How does this translate when there would be multiple loans? I.E. multiple loan ids

Comment: put the ID's into the `partition by` for each of the `OVER`'s

Comment: THANK YOU for your help!!! I struggle tremendously with these types of statements

Comment: In the same vain, how could I also sum the fees charged. So we have the count of fees per date, which is perfect but then also to sum it?